# Kept getting error 4058 on installation of react in my pc

Tags: reactjs, installation

So, i tried installing react from their official site, and followed the steps as mentioned there
it did install successfully but when i tried to start the react app it kept on giving me the error-4058. Here is the installation:-
C:\Users\soumo>npx create-next-app@latest
Need to install the following packages:
create-next-app@13.5.3
Ok to proceed? (y) y
√ What is your project named? ... my-app
√ Would you like to use TypeScript? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to use ESLint? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to use Tailwind CSS? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to use `src/` directory? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to use App Router? (recommended) ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to customize the default import alias? ... No / Yes
Creating a new Next.js app in C:\Users\soumo\my-app.

Using npm.

Initializing project with template: app-tw

Installing dependencies:

- react
- react-dom
- next

Installing devDependencies:

- typescript
- @types/react
- @types/node
- @types/react-dom
- autoprefixer
- postcss
- tailwindcss
- eslint
- eslint-config-next

added 330 packages, and audited 331 packages in 60s

117 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
Success! Created my-app at C:\Users\soumo\my-app

When i tried to start react:-
C:\Users\soumo>cd my-app

C:\Users\soumo\my-app>npm start

> my-app@0.1.0 start
> next start

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\soumo\my-app.next\BUILD_ID'] {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'C:\Users\soumo\my-app\.next\BUILD_ID'
}
-I tried restarting my pc
-installing dependencies
C:\Users\soumo\my-app>npm install

up to date, audited 331 packages in 2s

117 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details
still same error

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

or:

```
npm init react-app my-app
```

From the react documentation:

> If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm install -g create-react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package using npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app to ensure that npx always uses the latest version.
> https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

then start the local server:

```
npm start
```

I have this error too (when using):

> npx create-react-app myapp

and as of now those are the only solution for now
(I am running a newly built windows 11 pro machine)

Hope this helps!